# const string value contents not recognized in constructor

Tags: c++, file, constructor, io, constants

In Myclass.cpp:

```
const std::string FILE_NAME = "C:\\MyFileName.txt";

MyClass::MyClass() 
{
    ifstream fileToOpen;
    fileToOpen.open(FILE_NAME);   //FILE_NAME shows "" in debug
}

MyClass::OpenFile()
{
    ifstream fileToOpen;
    fileToOpen.open(FILE_NAME);   //when called from another location, this resolves to proper file name.
}
```

I'm trying to open a file in the constructor. When I call the open function on that file name, the constant variable resolves to `""`, but if the function is called elsewhere, it works perfectly fine.  I have tried this in the .h file with the same results. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Static initialization fiasco?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Nathan - what's wrong with my example.  short of surrounding it with braces to make it a compilable class, that's essentially everything i was trying to do.

Comment: Yes but you are not showing us where you are calling the constructor.  You should post a minimal amount of code that lets exhibits the behavior so we can try it ourselves.

Comment: @Jason It's not complete. If you try to just compile `Myclass.cpp` you'll see.

Comment: Do not use constants in UPPERCASE, that's antipattern, unless they are preprocessor macro

Comment: Wild guess - is your MyClass instance also a static variable?

Comment: @Jason - surround with braces?  is FILE_NAME part of your class?  I didn't think so before.  Yes, clarify more please.

Comment: Also, why is FILE_NAME a std::string rather than a simple const char*.

Comment: I updated the code with the second backslash.  my code has that, but in hand typing the example, i missed it.

MyClass is defined as a Global instance in another .h file.  It is not ideal nor pretty, but that's the legacy code i was handed.

Mr.Lister - does that matter?  it's just the choice i made.  i was not assuming any ill effects.

Slava - i wasn't aware that was an antipattern at all.

Comment: missing `void` for OpenFile, and `ifstream` is an incomplete type

Comment: @Jason So you are constructing a global object and when you do that the string is blank but if you construct a local object the string is good?

Comment: @KerrekSB - it was definitely the static init issue.  I wasn't aware of the fact that the way the legacy code created the constructors was essentially creating a static instance.

Nathan Oliver - as i said above, that does seem to be the case.  Obviously this was an issue on me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this happens because of the initialization order. The standard says (§3.6.2/2) that (regarding variables with static storage duration or thread storage duration)

> Variables with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order
>   of their definitions in the translation unit. <...> Otherwise, the initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the initialization
>   of a variable defined in a different translation unit.

Both `FILE_NAME` and the global instance of `MyClass` have static storage duration, and if they happen to be in different translation units, their order of initialization is undefined. So I would guess in your case the global variable of `MyClass` type got initialized before `FILE_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is to use a function that returns the file name instead of using a variable.

```
static std::string getFileName()
{
   return "C:\\MyFileName.txt";
}

MyClass::MyClass() 
{
    ifstream fileToOpen;
    fileToOpen.open(getFileName());
}
```